# Parse string with jsoup and string builder

Tags: android, jsoup, stringbuilder

Parse HTML with jsoup and string builder add white space in the final result.
First, it shows title and then strings from tag

between the string title and tag p there is white space. thankyou

MainActivity

```
 TextView tvidescription;

    @Override
protected void onCreate ( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

 new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run () {


                final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                try {
                    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://jang.com.pk/news/497717").get();
                    Elements links = doc.select("p");
                    String title = doc.title();
                    builder.append(title);

                    for (Element link : links) {

                        builder.append("\n").append("\n").append(link.text());
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    builder.append("Error : ").append(e.getMessage()).append("\n");
                }

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run () {
                        tvidescription.setText(builder);
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
doc.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false);
```

this will remove white spaces.

Comment: brother Saikrishna Rajaraman thankyou for your replay but it not work. I Place this after    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://jang.com.pk/news/497717").get();

Comment: You are appending 2 "\n" (newline characters) before adding the links text. Maybe that might be the issue.

Comment: in webpage, there are pictures in articles these picture cause white space